# Can I order results by the length of an object in the firebase firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a votes field in my firestore documents, in which I store the uids of the people that have voted on that document.

[image]

I would like to call all the documents and order them by the number of votes in the votes object.

I tried `db.collection('myCollection').orderBy(Object.keys('votes').length)...` but that is not valid as an orderBy parameter.

I also tried 'votes.size' but no luck.

Is there any way to order results of a query by the length of an object in the firebase firestore?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `votesCount` key to the documents and a firebase function that recalculates the count every time there is a vote. Then order on that.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is what I am doing at the moment. I was asking to find out if there was a way to calculate the value during the query request rather than having to save it explicitly.

Comment: Is it possible to check: where(votes.value,'==',true).orderBy(voteCount,'desc') ?

Comment: @abraham do you mean a cloud firestore function ? that would trigger everytime votes for example would change ?