# How to order documents by array field length in firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I got user objects in firestore database like the following,

```
{"username": "howawong", "tags": ["a", "b", "c"] }
```

How shall I query the documents by number of tags in descending order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an extra field i.e `tag_count`, which you update every time a tag is added/removed. You can update it with a firebase function or each time you update the document.

Same Question:
[Can I order results by the length of an object in the firebase firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746993/can-i-order-results-by-the-length-of-an-object-in-the-firebase-firestore)