# Sorting an docs by comparing the docs in a subcollection with the most recent date in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore structure like this:

```
chats > chat docs with unique IDs
```

Each chat doc contains these values:

```
id, members and more info on the chat like nicknames etc.
```

In addition, there is a subcollection containing all the messages,

```
the messages also each have their own doc id, a date, and message.
```

How can I sort the chat docs when fetching them from firebase based on the last message thst was sent given each message has a timestamp associated with it.

```
Is it possible to solve this without modifying the firestore structure?
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible with firestore.
What you can do is to add a 'lastMessageDate' field in your chat that is updated each time a message is sent, and you will be able to order by that 'lastMessageDate'

Comment: similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746993/can-i-order-results-by-the-length-of-an-object-in-the-firebase-firestore

Comment: For some reason, if I do this, my components are being rerendered any idea why that is?

Comment: Could you please update your question that includes how you render your data so that we could try to reproduce what you're seeing. And also, as @Florent stated, it's not possible with Firestore, for your use-case, you should rearrange your data on the client side before rendering your data.